# How to calculate this function related to gamma function?

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to calculate a value which uses Γ(1-x) in the function.

It shows domain error for any negative numbers with math library Gamma function, which is normal.

The goal value is : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpwxS.png)

```py
def fact(x,tmp=0,init=False):
    if not init:
        tmp = x
        init = True
    if x >= 0:
        if tmp <= 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return tmp * fact(x,tmp=tmp-1,init=init)
    elif x < 0:
        if tmp >= -1:
            return -1
        else:
            return tmp * fact(x,tmp=tmp+1,init=init)

x = -5
-(fact(x)/abs(x))
```

This code is valid for the goal ?

Comment: Are you asking about a specific math library?

Comment: if it's need library, it's not a problem, However, the math library use for the moment is math built-in library.

Comment: Please tag your question according to the language you are using, and add your code for clarification.

Comment: By definition gamma it's not for negative number, but I know the formula I want to calcul is correct, and Gamma function for negative value is possible, in solver like Mathematica it's not unallowed, so i ask me how do that.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=gamma%5C%2840%29-x%5C%2841%29

Comment: I'm not try to define a pole, juste reproduce function result in my post edit link

Comment: Your update makes the question completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Gamma cannot be computed at non-positive integers, full stop. No formula will help.

The built-in functions do compute Gamma for non-integer values.